# Flex pressed key 's charcode to string as UTF-8

Tags: apache-flex, string, utf-8

```
private function pressedLetter(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            pressedKeyLabel.text = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode); 
        }
```

According to code below, the letters such : "ı, ğ" could not be displayed at pressedKeyLabel, it shows different things. how can i display this letters correct ? thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Wouldn't it be better just to use a text input?

Comment: i'm coding a game and the user should pick up a letter from its keyboard and the application must be able to capture this key as an event. a text input is not user friendly. you have to click to text input than to the place the letter its location and all must be done in ten seconds. have you any solution or not ?

Comment: Wait, you're building a game with Flex?  I sure hope there's *a lot* of user interfaces to warrant that decision...

Comment: yes a small multi player game, i have coded the server side and half of the client side. now i need only to take correct letters. or i have to write me own a function (e.g charCodetoUtf) and have to manage with numbers where this game may be published for all languages so that i have to solve this problem carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you have an IME present.  keyCode and charCode are both off if using an IME because the default is an english keyboard, as [per the api](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#keyCode).

You'll need to use the IME class to [convert the string like this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cd5.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ccb).

Comment: at java, c# or such languages there are encoding options. are there not any for flex ? i've tried the "ime", but it seems i have to install extra things.

Comment: What do you mean install extra things?  Encoding is already set to utf-8 I believe.

Comment: if (Capabilities.hasIME) 
{ 
    if (IME.enabled) 
    { 
        trace("IME is installed and enabled."); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        trace("IME is installed but not enabled. Please enable your IME and try again."); 
    } 
} 
else 
{ 
    trace("IME is not installed. Please install an IME and try again."); 
}
check the code here ... how can i be sure the user has installed ime ?

Comment: If it has an IME, use the IME, if not, use the keyCode.  `Capabilities.hasIME` says if it's available.